# SymetricDS: How to define a trigger that matches all the tables except on

Tags: symmetricds

I have defined a SymmetricDS trigger that covers all my tables, like this:

```
INSERT INTO sym_trigger (trigger_id, source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, sync_on_update, sync_on_insert, sync_on_delete, sync_on_update_condition, sync_on_insert_condition, sync_on_delete_condition, last_update_time, create_time, sync_on_incoming_batch)
VALUES ('public.tables', 'public', '*', 'default', 1, 1, 1, '1=1', '1=1', '1=1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1);
```

But now I want to chage it in such a way that it will match all my tables, except for 'emails' table. I want 'emails' table to be excluded from the triggeres coverage.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use "*,!emails" for the source table name.  The source table name can be a comma-separated list of tables and allows asterisk for wildcard (*) and exclamation (!) for exclusion.

```
INSERT INTO sym_trigger (trigger_id, source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, sync_on_update, sync_on_insert, sync_on_delete, sync_on_update_condition, sync_on_insert_condition, sync_on_delete_condition, last_update_time, create_time, sync_on_incoming_batch)
VALUES ('public.tables', 'public', '*,!emails', 'default', 1, 1, 1, '1=1', '1=1', '1=1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1);
```

More information can be found in the SymmetricDS trigger wildcard documentation:

https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.14/html/user-guide.html#_trigger_wildcards